# Dissimilarity Matrix calculations

Tags: data-mining

I'm reviewing a section of Data Mining Statistics. My question is how do we determine (p - m)/p. How is the value of m calculated?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming - maybe try https://datascience.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

After working through the problem we can see that we have 4 objects. This produces a dissimilarity matrix 4x4. If we compare the attributes of object 4 and 1 for the nominal attribute test-1 there is a match for objects 4 and 1. Therefore, p=1, m=1 for d(4,1).